# Speed up asp.net Development server

Tags: iis, asp.net, web, visual-studio

I am running a website in ASP.Net using the development server, which is insanely slow to load  a page with no apparent reason since it is fast in production.   Are there any tips to speed up the ASP.net Development server or alternatives to using it?

Comment: Are you talking about the dev server that comes with Visual Studio?  And thus comparing that on your PC to server grade hardware and software?

Comment: I sense the tone and my response is that I am one person and the server is meant to handle thousands of simultaneous connection so your comment added 0 value.

Comment: There was no malice intended, sorry that you read it that way.  Do realize, though, that you gave us nothing as far as specs related to your situation.  Without more details as to what your environment is it will be hard to help you improve your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to do is add more memory to your machine.  There are no tuning options for the VS Dev Server.

You can also use IIS locally or a different web server altogether for your debugging.  This can be set in your project properties.  Go to the Web tab in your project properties and change the options under Servers.  You'll likely have some work to do on the web server in order to get the debugging hooked up properly.

Here's a good article on [**web servers you can use with Visual Studio**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx) (assuming VS2010 / .NET 4)

Answer (score 0):

Besides RAM, use SSDs throughout your development machine.
Try to measure what consumes the CPU time using a profiler (or "StopWatch" prints). Don't forget to debug through your global.asax.
Possibly it's the database or something else. Without measuring nobody can know.